# Is there a non-TLS (SSL v3 or lower) API endpoint for weather.gov?

Tags: weather-api, nws

It seems that since upgrading they now redirect to a TLS API endpoint. Is anyone aware of a transition api endpoint for the old api if it exists or where to find information regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

From Kolly Mars from the NWS:

"Thanks for reaching out to us.

I am afraid that we are bound by Binding Operational Directive 18-01 https://cyber.dhs.gov/bod/18-01/

WE are not able at this time to move from a secure web site to an insecure site. I am sorry this has impacted you. I'm not currently aware of any non https services for sunrise/sunset.

Thanks,
KM
"